# Как выполнить команду при открытии терминала в Arch Linux

Tags: linux, node.js, archlinux

Я установил node js  через nvm.
Для того чтобы иметь возможность в консоли просто выполнить "node -v" вначале мне нужно выполнить команду.

```
source /usr/share/nvm/init-nvm.sh
```

если этого не сделать то система не находит node

```
$ node -v
zsh: correct 'node' to '_node' [nyae]?
```

прочитал что можно добавить эту команду в файл `~/.bashrc`, и тогда при каждом открытии консоли она будет выполняться автоматически.

Команда добавлена

```
#
# ~/.bashrc
#

source /usr/share/nvm/init-nvm.sh
```

но node в терминале по-прежнему подсвечивается красным, не определяется.

подскажите, что не так делаю, как можно это исправить?

Answer (score 0):

Оказалось, что у меня терминал от zxh, что видно в вопросе.
поэтому строчку нужно было прописывать в `~/.zxhrc`

Comment: в вопросе вообще-то нет такого буквосочетания `zxh`